# Is it possible to have too many $PATHs set in OS X?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, shell, rubygems

I've been learning about gems lately, and one error I get is:

```
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and
  /usr/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/Alex/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
 gem executables will not run.
ERROR:  Error installing rubygame:
 ffi requires rake (>= 0.8.7, runtime)
```

I understand that UNIX (bash, more specifically) uses this .bash_profile file to know where to look for executables when I run a script/command, and that it does so "in order".

**My question is**: Can I just keep tacking directories on the end as I need them, and does doing this open me up to... anything?

(for what it's worth, I re-ran the command as "sudo gem..." and it still said "`ERROR:  Error installing rubygame:
 ffi requires rake (>= 0.8.7, runtime)`
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add stuff to the end (or to the top) of PATH until you reach the length limit for a variable. Which is loooooong.

But it slows command searches. Every time you type a command the the executable is searched everywhere the PATH tells it to search until found. Commands typos may lead to non-existing files and those could get slow to sort out.

Comment: Actually it depends of the shell (for the command searching). A clever shell like zsh (everybody should use it:P) keep a hash table of all the available commands, that's why you need to do "rehash" after installing something.

Comment: Ehm, *bash does hashing*. (check `help hash`) It's **lazy** hashing, yes. It doesn't search stuff it didn't already find. Then, also manually rehashing an active hash of a mastodontic path, can prove out to be a long operation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe bash caches the location of executables, so even if you have a long PATH it shouldn't take longer to run programs.

You could try `sudo gem update rake` for that last error...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any limits of how long the $PATH var or any one env var can be. But I guess there is a limit on environment variables in general, something like 65KB total. Still not sure.